# How to get the scope of an alias in powershell?

Tags: powershell

When creating an alias you can also set the **scope** of the alias using:

```
Set-Alias -Name find -Value Find-File -Scope Local -Option Private
```

However, when listing currently available aliases, I am not able to find a way to show the `Scope` of the alias. The closest I got was this:

```
Get-Alias | Format-Table -Property Name, Visibility, Options -Autosize

# cat           Public               None
# cd            Public           AllScope
```

There seem to be no `Scope` property...

Q: **How can I list all aliases showing their scope?**

---

References:

- [MS] [About Scopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-7.4)
- [MS] [`Set-Alias`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/set-alias?view=powershell-7.4)

Comment: Using `Get-Scope` you can specify which scope you want to list with the parameter `-Scope`. There are only 3 of them ... you may run the cmdlet 3 times to see all aliasses according to their scope. ‍♂️

Comment: Nope, you are confused. There are 5 scopes for [Set-Alias](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/set-alias?view=powershell-7.4) : `Global, Local, Private, Numbered scopes, Script`.

Comment: According to the documentation of the cmdlet `Get-Alias` there are 3. ‍♂️ [Get-Alias -Scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-alias?view=powershell-7.4#-scope)

Comment: IDK. My only explanation is that probably, the meaning of *scope* in Get-Alias is different from that used in Set-Alias? Either way, the *original* (Set-Alias) Scope doesn't seem retrievable from any single command.

Comment: Just out of curiousity ... whatfor do you need that?